# How to make a 2002 ISO image readable?

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image

I have downloaded (via torrent) an image of a good old game for Windows XP released in 2002 and I am trying to run it with WinXP on VirtualBox on OS X 10.9. I have downloaded a WinXP image from modern.ie, but I cannot attach the game image and get error:

```
Failed to open the optical disk file /Users/andrei/Downloads/game.iso.

Could not get the storage format of the medium 
'/Users/andrei/Downloads/game.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component:   Medium
Interface:   IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee:      IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC:   VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Running hdiutil also fails

```
$ hdiutil mount game.iso
hdiutil: mount failed - image not recognized
```

Other users have succeeded to install the game from the image on Windows.

Is there a way to convert the disk to a readable format or to extract the data?

Comment: I have just updated my question - the other users who have downloaded the ISO file have managed to install the game on Windows.

Comment: I have bought the game 10 years ago and lost the disk.

Comment: @Ramhound if you don't want to help him then don't help him.. I don't know how he should prove to you that he has the right to own the game. You could just give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Andrei You could Try some Windows apps for opening the ISO.  Magic ISO is one but better a free one.. i'll try to think of others. Virtual Clonedrive is fantastic  http://www.slysoft.com/en/download.html

Comment: @barlop yeah, I was thinking about it but then hell there must be a way to do it on Mac :/

Comment: @barlop I didn't claim he did.  But the benefit of the doubt on a game he download through BitTorrent instead of GOG or some other supported online retail channel.

Comment: "from **the** image" (that is, this exact image file)? Or some other download based on the same torrent file? In that case, have you verified that the ISO files are actually identical? (sha256sum will come in nicely.) My first thought when I saw "2002" was [bit rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation#Decay_of_storage_media), but if you haven't actually been storing the file for this time, it might not be. That'd depend on if whatever metadata was used to verify it represents an accurate copy... What happens if you simply try to mount it on the host?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It does not mount on Mac, but works perfectly fine in Daemon Tools as the accepted answer suggested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried mounting the .iso using a program like Virtual CloneDrive or Daemon Tools?

http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/Virtual-CD-DVD-Rom/Virtual-CloneDrive.shtml
http://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads

They both should run fine in a virtualised windowsXP.

Comment: @Andrei you forgot what? I mentioned Virtual Clonedrive in a comment 20min ago. Then you said there must be a way on a mac

Comment: @barlop Sorry, yes, I gave up - my memory of running daemon tools for several years just came up and won it :-D

Comment: @Andrei daemon tools is not as good because nowadays it has some adware you have to untick

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible to unzip the iso? You can download 7-zip and install it in XP. If this won't work, try other zip programs. In my experience 7-zip is one of the best in unzipping uncommon formats.

http://www.7-zip.org/